# 'newItem' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

Tags: c

hi how can i fix this error?
'newItem' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

```
int insertItem(const struct item *newItem){
int i;

if(itemNo == maxItem)return(0);
if(searchItemById(newItem.id) != -1)return(-1);

for(i=itemNo-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(newItem.id<itemList[i].id)
        itemList[i+1]= itemList[i];
    else break;
itemList[i+1] = newItem;
itemNo++;
return(2);
}
```

where is my wrong?

Comment: Pointers don't have members, so `newItem` has no `id` member that you can access.

Comment: It is literally telling you that you probably mean `newItem->id` instead of `newItem.id`, because `newItem` is a **pointer** to a struct. Don't skip important concepts when learning C.

Comment: @Cheatah now i have now error : error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'insertItem'| what is this ?

Comment: @saeed This is a failing strategy. Learn C from the basics, don't just do something until it works.

Answer (score 1):

> The . (dot) operator and the -> (arrow) operator are used to reference
> individual members of classes, structures, and unions.
>
> The dot operator is applied to the actual object. The arrow operator
> is used with a pointer to an object. For example, consider the
> following structure

Since `newItem` is a pointer if you want to access its member then you have to use -> (arrow) :

`newItem->member`

Or if you still want to use `. (dot)`, dereference it before accessing its member :

`(*newItem).member`